# Angular ngSelected not working in version > 1.3

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.6" data-semver="1.5.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <select ng-model="user.item_id">
      <option ng-selected="i.id == user.item_id" ng-repeat="i in items" value={{i.id}}>{{i.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var module = angular.module("test", []);

module.controller('ctrl', function($scope){

  $scope.items = [
    {id: 1, name: 'foo'},
    {id: 2, name: 'bar'},
    {id: 3, name: 'baz'},
  ];

  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.selectedItem = {id: 1};

  $scope.user.item_id = $scope.selectedItem.id;


});
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/7oi4KwzMhGi3kdltSklg?p=preview

Problem: if you inspect the html code of the `select`, you will see that the HTML `selected` attribute is properly placed.

However, it doesn't show as the highlighted option. Why?

**== EDIT ==**

That plunker code is working as expected on angular 1.3.20, but it's broken in 1.4.x or 1.5.x

Working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/0ApQeZ6Kar2yQisELXfT?p=preview

**== EDIT2 ==**

I've issued a ticket on angularjs queue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14876#issuecomment-231010972

Basically, they say we should stick to ngOptions, though they don't know why ngSelected got broken.

Comment: I don't see any difference between the plnkr with angular *1.3x* and angular *1.5x*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could use ng-options instead...

```
<select ng-model="user.item_id" ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in items">
</select>
```

Check here  https://plnkr.co/edit/G4Hu4ZpShaUPCE5zTsdV

Comment: That was a great one using ng-options

Comment: Yep i could, thank you - but that's not my point, i would like to understand why ng-selected seems to be broken.

Comment: Well the problem was with using $scope.selectedItem = {id: 1};
Try this $scope.selectedItem = {id: '1'}; and it works fine... You are comparing id string to id number, and so it doesn't match

Comment: [Check this other alternative](https://plnkr.co/edit/hXxz6a8Q4OKCY6e04Tei)

Comment: I see. Please check updated plunker version, in the options label, you'll see that the match is true. Still confused

Comment: Umm, I do see a bug there... However, the text displayed using {{ user }} shows that upon click a string is set... But, it is weird that it marks it as true the first time.

Comment: I've issued a bug in angularjs queue. I'll accept your answer since it solves, though it doesn't fully answer my actual question. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this working on any version that you mention. Anyway, check this plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/V0ybr70kRpkcaxLKBHTK?p=preview

The way that you wrote the select, i can reproduce the same thing on any input. And the reason is because it is not how angular binding works, your select doesn't know anything about his model, unless you change the model (i.e. using `ng-init`).

Using this way:

```
<option ng-selected="i.id == user.item_id" ng-repeat="i in items" value={{i.id}}>{{i.name}}</option>
```

doesn't mean that your model will update, it only updates the dom element.

Comment: Sorry mate, this is the same version with angular 1.3.20 https://plnkr.co/edit/0ApQeZ6Kar2yQisELXfT?p=preview and i see it working on chrome.